# Find missing coordinate in normalized vector

Tags: c++, math, vector, maxscript

Say I have a normalized vector but I don't know what the z coordinate is.  How can I retrieve the normalized z coordinate while preserving the existing x and y coordinates.

For example:

```
X: -0.361
Y:  0.361
Z:  ?
```

The length of just x and y is 0.510531

```
len = sqrt((ax * ax) + (ay * ay)) -- 0.510531
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What does it mean to have a normalized vector? It means that `|Vx|^2 + |Vy|^2 +|Vz|^2 = 1`. So, from standard algebra, it follows that `|Vz| = sqrt(1 - |Vx|^2 - |Vy|^2)`, which implies that `Vz` can take 2 values, negative and positive of `sqrt(1 - |Vx|^2 - |Vy|^2)`

And btw, the answer is the same in all programming languages ;) Math has nothing to do with C++.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply the positive or negative of the square root of:

```
1 - ax * ax - ay * ay
```